# Does the Message to WndProc change value from 32Bit OS to 64Bit OS?

Tags: c#, .net, wndproc

When the following Method is overrided in .NET it seems that I get different Messages in 32Bit and 64Bit OS:es. Can this be true?

`protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`

I want to catch the following: `private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;` but `WM_LBUTTONBLCLK` seem to have another "Id" in my windows 2003 64 bit installation  than it had on my Windows XP 32 Bit.

**Suggestions?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cannot be it, the message identifiers have not changed.  It would help us help you if you documented what other message you get instead or what kind of window or control you are hooking.  The only difference in Message relevant to WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK is that WParam and LParam fields are now 64 bits instead of 32 bits.  Hard to get that wrong though, surely you are using the ToInt32() method.

Comment: You are correct, it cannot be. The Message Id was in fact the correct one. Did however still wonder if it were the same for 32 bit as for 64 bit. Thanks for clearing that up.